# How can I optimize querying this data in postgresql?

Tags: performance, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that is slow for particular rows. Postgres is choosing to do a `Seq Scan` instead of using an `Index Scan` for some of the rows, I assume because it's actually going to be faster than using the index.

Here's the query plan using the indexes for a normal kind of workload: http://explain.depesz.com/s/1A2o :

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT "blocks".* FROM "blocks" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "blocks"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" WHERE "jobs"."project_id" = 1;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..166.27 rows=19 width=130) (actual time=0.092..4.247 rows=2421 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=350
   ->  Index Scan using index_jobs_on_project_id on jobs  (cost=0.29..18.81 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.044..0.099 rows=15 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (project_id = 1)
         Buffers: shared hit=17
   ->  Index Scan using index_blocks_on_job_id on blocks  (cost=0.42..36.67 rows=19 width=130) (actual time=0.021..0.133 rows=161 loops=15)
         Index Cond: (job_id = jobs.id)
         Buffers: shared hit=333
 Total runtime: 4.737 ms
(9 rows)
```

Here's the query plan choosing to do a sequential scan for a less normal kind of workload: http://explain.depesz.com/s/cJOd :

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT "blocks".* FROM "blocks" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "blocks"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" WHERE "jobs"."project_id" = 2;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hash Join  (cost=1138.64..11236.94 rows=10421 width=130) (actual time=5.212..72.604 rows=2516 loops=1)
 Hash Cond: (blocks.job_id = jobs.id)
 Buffers: shared hit=5671
 ->  Seq Scan on blocks  (cost=0.00..8478.06 rows=303206 width=130) (actual time=0.008..24.573 rows=298084 loops=1)
       Buffers: shared hit=5446
 ->  Hash  (cost=1111.79..1111.79 rows=2148 width=4) (actual time=3.346..3.346 rows=2164 loops=1)
       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 77kB
       Buffers: shared hit=225
       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on jobs  (cost=40.94..1111.79 rows=2148 width=4) (actual time=0.595..2.158 rows=2164 loops=1)
             Recheck Cond: (project_id = 2)
             Buffers: shared hit=225
             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_jobs_on_project_id  (cost=0.00..40.40 rows=2148 width=0) (actual time=0.516..0.516 rows=2164 loops=1)
                   Index Cond: (project_id = 2)
                   Buffers: shared hit=8
 Total runtime: 72.767 ms
(15 rows)
```

In the first case, the project has 15 jobs and 2421 blocks. In the second case, the project has 2164 jobs and 2516 blocks.

Is there a way to query this data so that the second workload isn't so slow? Or am I just approaching some kind of worst-case performance workload?

**Edit**

After updating the random_page_cost to 1.1 and re-running EXPLAIN for the slow query: http://explain.depesz.com/s/xKdd

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT "blocks".* FROM "blocks" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "blocks"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" WHERE "jobs"."project_id" = 2;

                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..7634.08 rows=10421 width=130) (actual time=0.025..10.597 rows=2516 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=9206
   ->  Index Scan using index_jobs_on_project_id on jobs  (cost=0.29..1048.99 rows=2148 width=4) (actual time=0.015..1.239 rows=2164 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (project_id = 32357)
         Buffers: shared hit=225
   ->  Index Scan using index_blocks_on_job_id on blocks  (cost=0.42..2.88 rows=19 width=130) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=2164)
         Index Cond: (job_id = jobs.id)
         Buffers: shared hit=8981
 Total runtime: 10.925 ms
(9 rows)
```

Much better! Looks like I need to invest some time in tuning the server config.

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: There are indexes on the `jobs.project_id` and `blocks.job_id` columns.

Comment: Please show the full `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) ...` not just `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: What about `jobs.id`?

Comment: As a nested loop over two index scans is so much faster than the hashjoin over a bitmap index scan, I'd say your random_page_cost does not accurately reflect your real performance, at least when data is cached in RAM or shared_buffers. Try setting `SET random_page_cost = 1.1`  and re-run in that session. You might also want to throw more `work_mem` at the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a nested loop over two index scans is so much faster than the hashjoin over a bitmap index scan, I'd say your `random_page_cost` does not accurately reflect your real performance, at least when data is cached in RAM or `shared_buffers`.

Try setting `SET random_page_cost = 1.1` and re-run in that session. You might also want to throw more `work_mem` at the problem.

If the `random_page_cost` adjustment is effective, you'll probably want to update `postgresql.conf` to reflect it. Note that 1.1 is a pretty extreme setting; the default is 4, and `seq_page_cost` is 1, so in the config file I'd start with something more like 2 or 1.5 to avoid making other plans worse.

Comment: Playing with `random_page_cost` had an enormously positive impact for some of my queries. Here's a good article that expands on performance improvements due to random_page_cost: [How a single PostgreSQL config change improved slow query performance by 50x](https://amplitude.engineering/how-a-single-postgresql-config-change-improved-slow-query-performance-by-50x-85593b8991b0)

Comment: For very fast storage backends (e.g. Intel Optane class or similar hardware with very low latency for QD1 random reads), I'd also recommend trying setting both `seq_page_cost` and `random_page_cost` to values way below 1.0. This makes sense if your IO is very fast compared to even your CPU performance. For example, try `seq_page_cost=0.1` and `random_page_cost=0.11` if you have lots of RAM, too.