# Make postgresql request faster

Tags: postgresql

```sql
SELECT
    referrer_id, count(id) as referrals_count
FROM users
WHERE referrer_id != 0
GROUP BY referrer_id
order by referrals_count desc
limit 10;
```

Now i have this request, i checked execution time and it was ~26ms on table with 150k+ rows. How can i make this request faster?

[Explain analyze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W7yH.png)

I tryed to create index on referrer_id field and index like: id DESC, but it isn't worked for me.

Comment: I doubt you can create an index that will help with counting (except, perhaps, if most users do not have a referrer at all - also consider storing `null` instead of `0` for them). But 26ms is quite good already, no?

Comment: i will try to set null, but i think it my database will have more than 1kk rows it will be very slow because execution time for send answer about 150-250ms and in sum its all will be about 0.5s, ty for ur comment!

Comment: It seems quite good as Bergi says, but also have you ever checked parallel data gathering? Probably, opening and closing coordinator/workers will be the bootleneck here, but it worths to try it with the recommendation of jjanes to have "parallel index-only scan". Also, you can try to optimize `random_page_cost` like here,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270105/how-can-i-optimize-querying-this-data-in-postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make this query particularly efficient, but given that your WHERE clause eliminates 2/3 of the table, a filtered index can probably help.

```
create index on users (referrer_id, id) where referrer_id<>0;
```

For me, this index makes it about 5 times faster than the seq scan. By including "id" in the index as well, you can get an index-only scan (as long as the table is well vacuumed) and by fetching the rows already sorted by referrer_id, you can avoid the work of the hashagg. And that combination makes it quite a bit faster.

If the "id" field is never null, then you can change `count(id)` to `count(*)` and will get the same answer.  This change means you no longer need to include "id" in the index in order to get the index-only scan.

And if referrer_id is always >= 0 (which is likely the case for an id column) you can change the where clause to `referrer_id > 0`, which will let get rid of the need for the rather esoteric WHERE clause on the index.

Both of those combined would leave you with the need for just an index on referrer_id, which I would guess you already have anyway.

But if sending the answer is 10 times slower than running the query in the first place, I would say you are working on the wrong part of the problem.

Comment: ty for ur answer! i will try to do this. Answer is 10 times slower because i sending message for users and i cant do this more fast than now.

Comment: i tryed to add index like in ur comment, but it isnt worked for me, i guess i can't anyway make this request more faster than now?